# Алгоритм перестановок

Tags: алгоритм

Извините,писать негде было.Нужно,чтобы программа,написанная на си++,выводила на экран все перестановки от 1 до n,причем только такие перестановки,которые начинаются с 1.

Comment: первое - строим в памяти граф таким образом, что бы были связаны вершины, где один элемент делиться на другой.А как это можно сделать?

Comment: а в чем проблема написать три строки?

   for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
     for (int j = 2; j<= n; j++) {
       if (i % j == 0) { add_node(i,j);}

реализацию add_node напишите сами - это просто добавить в вектор.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо

Comment: @KoVadim три строки -- это (из g Simon Thompson's Haskell: The Craft of Functional Programming):

    import Data.List
    perms [] = [[]]
    perms xs = [ x:ps | x <- xs , ps <- perms ( xs\\[x] ) ]

А предложения к Вашим трём строкам добавить реализацию add_node -- это уже "каша из топора"

Comment: ок, и как Ваш хаскель код поможет коду на с++? я знаю, что на хаскеле код часто выглядит сильно просто. Если решили блеснуть хаскелем, тогда напишите полное решение. А то выглядит как будто Вы просто бездумно скопипастили.

Comment: @KoVadim разумеется, это копи/паст. А что Вы называете полным решением? Добавить ввод-вывод? Тем более, что для перестановок вообще-то в модуле `Data.List` есть функция `permutation`

Comment: написать решение задачи. Полный текст задачи внизу.

Comment: Полное решение было бы неплохо,хотелось понять а то я не совсем понял как решать по методам,которые дал KoVadim

Comment: @KoVadim

    import System.IO (stdout, hFlush)
    import Data.List ((\\))
    perms [] = [[]]
    perms xs = [ x:ps | x <- xs , ps <- perms ( xs\\[x] ) ]
    main = do
      putStr "Enter n>"
      hFlush stdout
      n <- read `fmap` getLine
      mapM_ (putStrLn . show) $ perms [1..n]

Или

    import System.IO (stdout, hFlush)
    import Data.List (permutations)
      main = do
      putStr "Enter n>"
      hFlush stdout
      n <- read `fmap` getLine
      mapM_ (putStrLn . show) $ permutations [1..n]

что больше нравится?

Comment: К сожалению,я не знаю хаскель,знаю си++,паскаль

Comment: @alexlz Ваш алгоритм генерирует перестановки. А в задаче нужно немного другое. Прочитайте внимательно условие задачи. Очень внимательно. Я даже скопирую ее сюда

> Задача состоит в следующем надо найти такую перестановку от 1 до n(начинаться должна с единицы)(если их несколько то без разницы какую) так чтобы получить максимальное число делящихся нацело соседних элементов в перестановке,например при n=9 (1,9,3,6,2,4,8,5,7) девять делится на единицу,следующая пара 9 делится на 3 нацело,следующая пара 6 делится на 3 нацело и т.д

Answer (score 5):

Видимо под найти подразумевается "распечатать"? Ну тогда у меня для Вас плохие новости. Для 15 элементных перестановок их кол-во будет равно 1307674368000 - даже если по одному байту на перестановку (чего явно не хватит), то это уже больше терабайта. А если это на печать выводить, то это будет по 16 байт на перестановку (15 символов + перевод строки).

Я потестил у себя скорость вывода на терминал - получилось порядка 450000 символов в секунду (хотя некоторые источники утверждают, что она порядка 33к символов в секунду. Я просто сделал time cat файл и посмотрел, сколько выводит). Из этого получается

15! * 16 / 447121 / 60/60/24 = 541 день = почти 2 года.

Вывод, никакой алгоритм тут не поможет.

Если в Вашей задаче написано "посчитать кол-во перестановок, которые удоволетворяют определенному условию, то тут нужно обычно придумывать специальный алгоритм". Этим любят увлекаться разные олимпиадные задачи (сам решал, знаю).

Comment: есть,небольшая загвоздка надо распечатать  все перестановки от 1 до n,которые начинаются с 1.Как здесь может помочь гамильтов цикл?

Comment: как может помочь гамильтонов цикл - не знаю. Но для данного уточнения алгоритм формируется так: нужно распечатать все перестановки от 2 до n, приписав в начало 1 для каждого вывода. Скорость по сравнению с полным перебором и отсеиванием ненужных вариантов возрастет в n раз.

Comment: Необязательно именно гамильтов цикл,меня интересует можно ли решить задачу перебора перестановок с помощью графовых методов?Если да,то как это можно реализовать

Comment: решение есть, надо копать в сторону рекуррентных соотношений

Comment: думаю можно и графами решать. Главное понимать сложность.

Comment: каким методом можно решить через графы?

Comment: через графы я не знаю. Если задача звучит просто "перебрать все, которые начинаются с 1", то графы тут не помогут. Сложность (я не о сложности кода, а о сложности алгоритмической). Уточните задачу - может быть там есть более простые варианты.

Comment: Задача состоит в следующем надо найти такую перестановку от 1 до n(начинаться должна с единицы)(если их несколько то без разницы какую) так чтобы получить максимальное число делящихся нацело соседних элементов в перестановке,например при n=9 (1,9,3,6,2,4,8,5,7) девять делится на единицу,следующая пара 9 делится на 3 нацело,следующая пара 6 делится на 3 нацело и т.д

Comment: первое - строим в памяти граф таким образом, что бы были связаны вершины, где один элемент делиться на другой. А дальше берем готовый алгоритм на графе [Алгоритм Куна нахождения наибольшего паросочетания в двудольном графе](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching) и/или [Алгоритм Эдмондса нахождения наибольшего паросочетания в произвольных графах](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/matching_edmonds).

Comment: скорость возрастает в n раз.. относительно чего? Как была (n-1)! так и осталась

Comment: хотя да, возможно "подвох" в том, чтобы подловить поциента на генерации n! перестановок и их фильтрации...

Comment: Первым делом нужно пустить по боку простые числа `> n/2`

Answer (score 0):

[[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) а вот, примерно, как это (perms) будет на c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
void perms(list<int> l, list<int> l1) {
    if(l1.size() == 0) {
        for(auto& i: l) cout << i << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    else {
        list<int> t = l;
        for(list<int>::iterator it = l1.begin(); it !=l1.end(); it++) {
            list<int> t1 = l1;
            t.push_back(*it);
            t1.remove(*it);
            perms(t, t1);
            t.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter n>";
    cin >> n;
    list<int> l, l1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) l1.push_back(i);
    perms(l, l1);
    return 0;
}
```

Ну, правда, вместо возврата списка списков я сразу вывожу на cout.

**UPD**

[[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim): кстати, к какому вопросу Ваш комментарий?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
void perms(list<int> l, list<int> l1, pair<int*, int>& res) {
    if(l1.size() == 0) {
        int *v =new int[l.size()];
        int n = 0;
        for(auto& i : l) v[n++] = i;
        n = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < l.size()-1; i++)
            if(v[i] > v[i+1]) n += !(v[i] % v[i+1]);
            else              n += !(v[i+1] % v[i]);
        if(n > res.second) {
            for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) res.first[i] = v[i];
            res.second = n;
        }
        delete []v;
        //for(auto& i: l) cout << i << ' ';
        //cout << endl;
    }
    else {
        list<int> t = l;
        for(list<int>::iterator it = l1.begin(); it !=l1.end(); it++) {
            list<int> t1 = l1;
            t.push_back(*it);
            t1.remove(*it);
            perms(t, t1, res);
            t.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter n>";
    cin >> n;
    list<int> l, l1;
    pair<int*, int> res;
    res.first = new int[n];
    res.second = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) l1.push_back(i);
    perms(l, l1, res);
    cout << res.second << ':';
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) cout << ' ' << res.first[i];
    cout << endl;
    delete [] res.first;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KoVadim обновил ответ

Comment: Кстати, убрав создание-удаление res.first для каждой комбинации на n==10 уменьшил user time на 0.2c с хвостиком.

Comment: плохой ответ. Он не решает задачу

    Enter n>9
    7: 4 8 2 6 3 9 1 5 7

а должно как минимум начаться с 1.

при 11 оно пару минут поработало и ничего не нашло (правда я его прервал). У ТС оно похоже плохо работает при <=15.

Второй код не решает задачи.

Comment: В первом коде ошибка, for(auto& i: l) cout << i << ' ';не запускается программа

Comment: это не ошибка, это новый синтаксис. Если используете Линукс (g++), тогда нужно компилировать с параметром `-std=c++0x` или `-std=c++11`. В случае студии ищите нужную опцию, но работать будет вроде только с 2010 студии (не уверен).

Comment: у меня 2010 только все равно не работает,а как эту строчку можно переделать?

Comment: for(auto& i : l)

заменяется на 

    for(int i = 0; i< l.size(); i++) 

а в коде нужно вместо `i` писать `l[i]`. Со списками это малоэффективно, лучше через итераторы переписать.

Comment: Выводит одну строчку от 0 до n,но это же бред какой-то

Comment: @KoVadim ну списки (list) -- это не вектор (vector). Поэтому индексации там нету.

А вообще всё это -- игра в хешкодугадайку. Есть задача. Пользователь задаёт вопрос "У меня есть задача, какая -- не скажу, но некоторые намёки дам. Очень нужно. Помогите решить." Тут Вы немного засветили задачу (потом я этого комментария не нашёл) -- найти максимум пар, где один из соседей делится на другого без осататка. Понятно, что полный перебор по перестановкам тут не катить -- перестановок n!. А дальше разговор имеет смысл продолжать, если ТС (и Вы тоже) прекратит играть в эту хешкодугадайку.

Comment: @alexlz я помню, что списки - не векторы. призабыл. Вопрос автор уточнил.

@ivan145 пишите полностью задачу, иначе получите снова кусок ответа.

Comment: @ivan145 немного больше конкретности. Нужна процедура, которая выводит на stdout все перестановки, нужна функция, возвращающая все перестановки (в каком виде?), ещё что-то (итератор по перестановкам или ещё что)?

Answer (score 0):

А так ?  ;)

```
const int N = 4;  /// Кол-во вершин гамильтонова графа. То есть  перестановки для 1,2,3,4

void Visit(int p_iNode, int&);
void WriteVarr();


vector<int> m_varrInt(N, 0);
int m_count=1;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int  v_iNow =0;


    for(int i=0; i < N; i++ )  ///{Перебираем пути, начинающиеся в вершинах 1, …, n}
        Visit(i, v_iNow);

    return 0;
}


void Visit(int p_iNode, int& p_iNow)
{
    p_iNow++; 

    m_varrInt[p_iNode] = p_iNow;


    if( p_iNow == N )
        WriteVarr();
    else 
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            if( m_varrInt[i] == 0 )
                Visit(i, p_iNow);
        }
    }

    p_iNow--;
    m_varrInt[p_iNode] = 0;
}


void WriteVarr()
{
    cout << m_count++ << ") " ;

    for(int i = 0; i < m_varrInt.size(); i++)
        cout << m_varrInt[i];

    cout << endl;
}
```